# How to list YII namespaces in default?

Tags: php, yii

In Yii framework, I find the `\Yii` namespaces.

how to list all kinds namespace of `yii framework`?

Comment: Where did you get the information that PHP namespace is case-sensitive? the [document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) says it is **case-insensitive**

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am not sure which kind of list you want but you can find all namespace on API documentation,

Hope below link will be useful to you.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0